# How do you find the points of intersection for multiple exponential functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I have these two equations, and cannot work out how to calculate the points of intersection (other than at $K=0$), yet my graphical calculator shows them to intersect three times. Thanks in advance.

$$5e^{-\frac{81K^{2}}{100}}+\frac{18K}{10}=5e^{-\frac{121K^{2}}{100}}+\frac{22K}{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

You might use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), for finding the roots of $f(x) = 5e^{-\frac{81x^{2}}{100}}+\frac{18x}{10}-5e^{-\frac{121x^{2}}{100}}-\frac{22x}{10}$